# auto Ik just doesn't work anymore

Tags: animation

I was working perfectly then it suddenly stops working... no more automatic ik, I know someone already asked this here [Bone Turns Orange And Auto IK Doesn't Work](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/203711/bone-turns-orange-and-auto-ik-doesnt-work) but mine doesn't turn orange and nothing of what the answers suggested works.

[image]

Comment: AutoIK is still working for me in 3.5.0.  I'd suspect your problem is that the bones you're trying to pose lack the "connected" property; autoIK uses this to determine the virtual chain length of the IK.  You can check this property by selecting a bone and looking on properties/bone/relations; you can set, in edit mode, from the same place, or through a ctrl-p set parent operation.

Comment: If Nathan's answer doesn't help, maybe share the armature so that we can test, and tell what bone you're trying to move?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @moonboots I pretty sure my file was just corrupted, I tried reimporting everything to another blender file and auto  IK started working again

Comment: @Nathan the bones were connected, have been using it for hours then it suddenly sopped working for some reason, i tried various solutions on the internet, even asked chatgpt but nothing... the only thing that worked was exporting everything as FBX then importing it again in another blender file. although it messed up all my animation names by adding "armature|armature :    " behind the name of every animation